# React-Native : react-native-fast-image not working properly with react-native, it give error

Tags: android, build.gradle, android-manifest, react-native

When I use React-native-fast-image with react-native, it throws an error

```
    * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-138 to override.
```

my package.json file is

```
    {
  "name": "FastImageDemmo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.0",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^7.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.4",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.55.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

my app.gradle is

```
dependencies {
implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
```

}

I have tried many solutions like  adding following code in  gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

but solution not working.

what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

My issue has been resolved by :

```
 "react": "16.8.6",
 "react-native": "0.60.4",
 "react-native-fast-image": "^7.0.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue has been resolved by downgrading version on react-native-fast-image from **7.0.2** to **6.0.3**